# jQuery, $.ajax how to work in ie7, 8 or 9?

Tags: jquery

my below ajax code not work in ie 7,8 or 9,

for ie data not display, how to fix it?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://www.wideawakemarketing.com/sbt-post/",
        data: {},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: What does "not work" mean in your use case? What do you expect to happen that's not happening exactly?

Comment: your breaking the same domain policy (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Comment: -1. Not enough info. jQuery ajax works perfectly well in IE 7/8/9 (assuming you're using jQuery v1.x and not v2.x). What errors are you getting? Have you checked the console? Do you know what line it is failing on? Why not? Does it work in other browsers? etc etc etc. You need to give a *lot* more detail.

Comment: Try to use cache: false,  maybe. And check data returned, if any

Comment: The `document.write(element.title);` pretty much wipes the document, is that desired?

Comment: In IE, hit that F-12 key, look at that console and relay any errors it provides and add any other additional information you can provide (like what "data" returns - exactly etc.) otherwise, this is unanswerable in its current form.  Does this work in Chrome or Fox for instance?

Answer (score -1):

As comments have mentioned, you cannot make an AJAX call to another domain without it supporting [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). *See [What is JSONP all about?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about) for more information*

I'd also like to mention a change, as of [jQuery 2.0](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/04/18/jquery-2-0-released/) which is that it **no longer supports IE 6, 7 & 8**. So if you're using the new 2.x version of jQuery, you'll most likely run in to issues with various things being "broken" when trying them in the older versions of IE.

Comment: People downvoting and blatantly annoying the orange popup are becoming common practice on here these days I guess. @downvoter: what gives?